# Regex to split on commas unless within square brackets - ignore nested square brackets

Tags: regex

I have a string of key value pairs. I want to split at the end of each pair.

I have a regex to split on commas that are not included in square brackets which works well except in the case where the content of the square brackets has another set of square brackets.

For example using the following string  (separated out to display the key value pairs easily):

```
info="Doing something", 
thisisok=["this", "works"], 
result=1, 
problem=["this", "fails[]"],
```

I get a match for the comma between "this" and "fails" due to the [] within the square brackets. I only want to match all of the , at the end of each pair.

I am currently using the following regex:

```
,(?![^\[]*\])
```

I expect to get 4 matching commas instead of 5. I need some change that excludes ] when it is immediately preceded by [

Comment: Are you sure there is `"works],` and not `"works"],`? I would try a matching approach instead. However, if the string does not follow any syntax rules, I doubt a 100% safe regex can be devised.

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes sorry that is a typo, it should be "works"]. (Updated). Can you clarify what you mean by matching approach?

Comment: Match with https://regex101.com/r/HRkkDl/1/

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for your response. My string may not always have double quotes which I think your regex depends on. I have updated my sample data to reflect this.Thanks again.

Comment: Not a big deal, see https://regex101.com/r/HRkkDl/2